# Vue 3 and cookies

Tags: vue.js, cookies, vuejs2, vue-cli-3, fastapi

I am building a frontend in Vue 3 and backend with fastAPI. I'd like to use httponly in the authentication process but I don't see in the browser that the cookie is received. I have checked with Postman the request to backend and I see the "set-cookie" with the data from backend.

Frontend:

- Vue 3
- Axios 0.18.1
- url: 127.0.0.1:8080

Backend:

- FastAPI
- uvicorn
- url: 127.0.0.1:8000

In the frontend the post message with Axios is like:

```
axios
    .post(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + '/login', this.auth, {withCredentials: true})
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
```

and in backend I configure explicit origins:

```
    origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

and when I return the response to frontend:

```
    response.set_cookie(
        key="Authorization",
        value=f"Bearer {token}",
        domain="127.0.0.1",
        path="/login",
        httponly=True,
        secure=False,
        max_age=1800,
        expires=1800,
    )
```

thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following changes and now it is working:

Frontend:

.env.development file:

```
NODE_ENV=development
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://localtest.me:8000
```

Backend:

```
origins = [
"http://localhost",
"http://localhost:8080",
"http://localtest.me",
"http://localtest.me:8080"
```

]

```
response.set_cookie(
        key="Authorization",
        value=f"Bearer {token}",
        domain="localtest.me",
        path="/",
        httponly=True,
        secure=False,
        max_age=1800,
        expires=1800,
    )
```